# Return class from method in mocked method. Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have class TaskType. It has method

```
public Class<? extends TaskParameters> getTypeParameters() {
    return typeParameters;
}
```

next i want to mock this class and mock this method:

```
    final TaskType TEST_PARAMETERS = Mockito.mock(TaskType.class);
    when(TEST_PARAMETERS.getTypeParameters()).thenReturn(ScheduledParameters.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(4).when(TEST_PARAMETERS).ordinal();
```

but i got problem:

```
error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(java.lang.Class<com.ucp.shard.bulkops.service.executor.ScheduleExecutorTest.ScheduledParameters>)
        when(TEST_PARAMETERS.getTypeParameters()).thenReturn(ScheduledParameters.class);
```

Help, how can i mock this method?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing a lot of information, it would be nice if you could update it. For example, you could share the code for `TaskType`.

First of all, it seems that `TaskType` is an enum as you are trying to call `ordinal()`, right? If it's the case, you need to remember that **enums are final and cannot be mocked by Mockito by default** (please read [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) for more information). If it's not an enum you can ignore it. :)

Regarding the problem mocking `getTypeParameters()`, you cannot do it directly due to type erasure (more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)). However, you can solve it using Mockito [Answer](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html):

```
final TaskType TEST_PARAMETERS = Mockito.mock(TaskType.class);
final Answer<Class<ScheduledParameters>> answer = invocation -> ScheduledParameters.class;
when(TEST_PARAMETERS.getTypeParameters())
    .thenAnswer(answer);
Mockito.doReturn(4).when(TEST_PARAMETERS).ordinal();
```